# C# Public Property unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically loading a control and passing through text to the control. But i'm getting an unhandeled exception on when i'm setting the public property.

My control is:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace g247_Test.controls
{
    public partial class carousel_guards : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public String pcode
        {
            get
            {
                return pcode;
            }
            set
            {
                pcode = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Loading the control on the previous page with:

```
   carousel_guards webUserControl = (carousel_guards)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx");

            webUserControl.pcode = "rg402eg";
            phGuardsList.Controls.Add(webUserControl);
```

The error goes on the set { saying just unhandled exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property is referencing itself. You may change it to:

```
 public String pcode { get; set; }
```

Or define a private string field and use that:

```
private string _pcode;

public string Pcode
{
    get { return _pcode; }
    set { _pcode = value; }
}
```

Also its better if you start the property name with Upper case, (Use [Pascal case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a stack overflow exception. You're basically telling the return to return itself which goes on forever.

You can do what Habib said and use the `get; set;` syntactic sugar but if you want a little more control the typical way to handle this is to create a field to store the value like so:

```
private string _pcode;

public string pcode { get { return _pcode; } set { _pcode = value; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing the get and set you're referencing the property itself; you should either A) have an underlying variable to hold the value that is inaccessible to the caller, or use B) [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

```
private string _pcode
public String pcode {
  get { return _pcode; }
  set { _pcode = value; }
}
```

Or,

```
public String pcode { get; set; }
```